# foursquare venue explore: selecting multiple sections

Tags: foursquare

The API seems to allow only one section (food, coffee, etc) and not multiple sections in one query. Am I missing something? How can I circumvent this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're doing a venue search, then you can include a list of category ids that are comma separated:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?near=washington, dc&categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d113951735,4bf58dd8d48988d17c941735,4bf58dd8d48988d153941735
```

> **Note:** If you copy paste this URL into a browser, it wont work.  You need to add your own oauth key param to the URL.

Comment: So I should choose search, and not 'explore'?

Answer (score 0):

Now foursquare API supports for multiple sections. 
Try giving

```
"sections=food,drinks,shop"
```

comma seperated sections are working fine.